# Union Static Value with in Xpath Query

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

How to union Static values with Xpath Query

Below is my XML Data

```
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

With below Xpath queries, i can able to achieve the values of Node Name

```
1) breakfast_menu/food[not(name=preceding-sibling::food/name)]/name
```

Out Put:

```
Belgian Waffles
Strawberry Belgian Waffles
```

My Intention is to Append the value 'ALL' to the output.

below Xpath queries are my work outs Using Union Operator to achieve

```
1) breakfast_menu/food[not(name=preceding-sibling::food/name)]/name | //food[name="ALL"]
```

Excepted Out Put with Xpath:

```
ALL
Belgian Waffles
Strawberry Belgian Waffles
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I re-written my question. hope now you will be understanding. Please check it @JensErat

Comment: Why you want to achieve that with an XPath? If you always want to add "All" to your output, why not put that directly in your output? Or maybe cover that with an XSL if?
Also you xPath is very complex, why not use a simple `//food/name` to retrieve all food names?

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for reply, Here i am actually developing a Jasper reports using XML as data source and my XML files are dynamic thus i had no scope of adding ALL in output.

More over i need to use this at input control level. I cant enter input control values statically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really have XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(('ALL', distinct-values(breakfast_menu/food/name)), '\n')
```

will yield a single string with lines

```
ALL
Belgian Waffles
Strawberry Belgian Waffles
```

If you want a sequence of strings then simply use

```
'ALL', distinct-values(breakfast_menu/food/name)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I tried as it is suggested. But i am getting this error while executing both of the above query:

`Error:DOMXPath::evaluate() [<a href='domxpath.evaluate'>domxpath.evaluate</a>]: Invalid expression`

I am using the below link for trail and error, I request to have a look at this link

[link]http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

You can get the data source from w3schools [link] http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

Unfortunately i am unable to share my screen shot here at comment box. Please let us know your further suggestions on this issue

Comment: @Naveen, well if I make a suggestion saying you need XPath 2.0 then you need to use an XPath 2.0 processor or API. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php supports XPath 1.0 so it will give you a syntax error or unknown function error on XPath 2.0 expressions.

Comment: ,hey i did replied under answer section where i have also shared a screen shot,please have a look at it

Comment: Honned, Dude It was Working, Thanks for your answer, I have tested it in another Xpath2 tester [link] http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi and here it was working but it was not working in Jasper ireport. Now i need to check with its community forum.